# TableView DidSelectRowAt() latency

Tags: uitableview, swift4.2

Hello I actually use a tableview in my app. I have this lines of code which switch from a VC to a mother and it work fine everywhere :

```
 let vue = MAINSTORYBOARD.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "accueil") as! Accueil
self.present(vue, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In my tableView I use the function DidSelectRowAt ( this execute when I click on a row/cell) to do this (switch of VC)
But you've already understood when I click it work but with latency. 
This latency can is sometimes 1-2s sometimes up to 12s it's random. That's weird.
I specify the function above work instantly with buttons and others.
 this is the code (I write only important things) :

```
class Horaire: ViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vue = MAINSTORYBOARD.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "accueil") as! Accueil
        self.present(vue, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

and the other class :

```
class Accueil: ViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewDidLoad executed")
    }
}
```

So when I click on a cell of my tableview it immediately print "viewDidLoad executed" but VC switch is done only after some random seconds. 
Why does I have this latency and how to fix it ? it don't use segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that came to my mind was to put the block in the main queue. I know `didSelectRowAt` is supposed to run in the UI thread, but I saw on the internet a couple complaints about this very same thing. Looks like a bug to me.

```
class Horaire: ViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
        let vue = MAINSTORYBOARD.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "accueil") as! Accueil
        self.present(vue, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

You can see for some odd reason this seemed to work for these people:
https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero/issues/79

Comment: Did you mingled class and extension ?

Comment: I did, I changed some of the code to test on my computer, and forgot to edit in the answer. You can change that back to `class`, or keep it as an extension and delete the `ViewController` bit. I will make the modification to my answer. My bad.

Comment: Si you tested this, it work ? Can you explain me what is the queue ?

Comment: It does work when you add some code to populate the table; which was not present in your class.

Comment: So I just have to add DisparchQueue.main.sync at it will work ? What did that do ?

Comment: Swift uses queues to handle threading. Blocks of code are put into queues, and they are executed by the processor. The queue that is responsible for updating the UI elements is the main queue. This is why you want to execute all UI related code in the main queue. Normally, `didSelectRowAt` should already be called on the main thread, but I saw too many people complaining about it on the internet that there might be a bug. Explicitly putting the block in the queue should make sure it's run in the main queue
https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2